# Getting issue with python Web scraping

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python and web scraping. I wrote some code for scraping quotes and the corresponding author name from `https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/inspirational-quotes` and ended with no result. Here is the code i used for the purpose,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Sandheep\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")

product = []
prices = []

driver.get("https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/inspirational-quotes")

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

for a in soup.findAll("a", href=True, attrs={"class": "clearfix"}):
    quote = a.find("a", href=True, attrs={"title": "view quote"}).text
    author = a.find("a", href=True, attrs={"class": "bq-aut"}).text

    product.append(quote)
    prices.append(author)

print(product)
print(prices)
```

I am not getting where i need to edit to get the result.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand site has this information in attribute alt of images. Also, quote and author separated by `' - '`.
So you need to iterate by `soup.find_all('img')`, the function to fetch result may look like:

```
def fetch_quotes(soup):
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        try:
            quote, author = img['alt'].split(' - ')
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            yield {'quote': quote, 'author': author}
```

Then, use it like: `print(list(fetch_quotes(soup)))`

Also, note, it is often that you can replace using `selenium` to pure `requests`, e.g.:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = requests.get("https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/inspirational-quotes").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"ChromeDriver path")


driver.get("https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/inspirational-quotes")

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

root_tag=["div", {"class":"m-brick grid-item boxy bqQt r-width"}]
quote_author=["a",{"title":"view author"}]

quote=[]
author=[]


all_data = soup.findAll(root_tag[0], root_tag[1])
for div in all_data:
    try:
        quote.append(div.find_all("a",{"title":"view quote"})[1].text)
        author.append(div.find(quote_author[0], quote_author[1]).text)
    except:
        continue
```

The output Will be:

```
for i in range(len(author)):
    print(quote[i])
    print(author[i])
    break

Start by doing what's necessary; then do what's possible; and suddenly you are doing the impossible.
Francis of Assisi
```